# Cannot borrow value from a hashmap as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust, hashmap

I want to get two values from a hashmap at the same time, but I can't escape the following error, I have simplified the code as follows, can anyone help me to fix this error.

```
#[warn(unused_variables)]
use hashbrown::HashMap;

fn do_cal(a: &[usize], b: &[usize]) -> usize {
    a.iter().sum::<usize>() + b.iter().sum::<usize>()
}

fn do_check(i: usize, j:usize) -> bool {
    i/2 < j - 10
}

fn do_expensive_cal(i: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    vec![i,i,i]
}

fn main() {
    let size = 1000000;
    let mut hash: HashMap<usize, Vec<usize>> = HashMap::new();
    for i in 0..size{
        if i > 0 {
            hash.remove(&(i - 1));
        }
        
        if !hash.contains_key(&i){
            hash.insert(i, do_expensive_cal(i));
        }
        let data1 = hash.get(&i).unwrap();
    
        for j in i + 1..size {
            if do_check(i, j) {
                break
            }
            if !hash.contains_key(&j){
                hash.insert(j, do_expensive_cal(j));
            }
            let data2 = hash.get(&j).unwrap();
            let res = do_cal(data1, data2);
            println!("res:{}", res);
    
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be292cf1672e4aacab6746bc16ffaa74)

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `hash` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

```
  --> src/main.rs:26:8
   |
19 |         let data1 = hash.get(&i).unwrap();
   |                     ------------ immutable borrow occurs here
...
26 |                 hash.insert(j, vec![1,2,3]);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
29 |             let res = do_cal(data1, data2);
   |                              ----- immutable borrow later used here
```

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error

Comment: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` is the default, you don't need to specify it.

Comment: Also `hashbrown::HashMap` is (almost) the same as `std::collections::HashMap`, you don't need an external dependency for it.

Comment: my test shown `hashbrown::HashMap` is faster than `std::collections::HashMap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this: the borrow checker doesn't know that `hash.insert(j, …)` will leave the data you inserted with `hash.insert(i, …)` alone. For the borrow checker, `hash.insert(…)` may do anything to any element in `hash`, including rewriting or removing it. So you can't be allowed to hold the reference `data1` over `hash.insert(j, …)`.

How to get over that? The easiest is probably to move `let data1 = hash.get(…)` so it doesn't have to live for so long:

```rust
let data1 = hash.get(&i).unwrap();
let data2 = hash.get(&j).unwrap();
let res = do_cal(data1, data2);
```

This will of course look up `data1` every loop iteration (and it must, since `hash.insert(j, …)` may have resized and thus realocated the content of the hashmap, giving `data1` a new storage location in the hashmap). For completeness's sake, there are ways to get around that, but I don't recommend you do any of this:

- Clone: `let data1 = hash.get(&i).unwrap().clone()` (if your vecs are short, this may actually be reasonable…)
- As a way of making the cloning cheap, you could use a `HashMap<usize, Rc<Vec<usize>>>` instead (where you only need to clone the `Rc`, no the entire `Vec`)
- If you ever need mutable references to both arguments of `do_call`, you could combine the `Rc` with a `RefCell`: `Rc<RefCell<Vec<…>>>`
- If you need to overengineer it even more, you could replace the `Rc`s with references obtained from allocating in a bump allocator, e.g. [bumpalo](https://docs.rs/bumpalo/latest/bumpalo/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html).

Comment: Note that `hash.insert (j, …)` will _not_ leave the data from `hash.get (i)` alone since `insert` may reallocate, which will result in the data moving around in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since the keys to the hash table are the integers 0..100 you can use a `Vec` to perform these steps, temporarily splitting the `Vec` into 2 slices to allow the mutation on one side. If you need a `HashMap` for later computations, you can then create a `HashMap` from the `Vec`.

The following code compiles but panics because the `j - 10` calculation underflows:

```rust
fn do_cal(a: &[usize], b: &[usize]) -> usize {
    a.iter().sum::<usize>() + b.iter().sum::<usize>()
}

fn do_check(i: usize, j:usize) -> bool {
    i/2 < j - 10
}

fn main() {
    let size = 100;
    let mut v: Vec<Option<Vec<usize>>> = vec![None; size];
    for i in 0..size {
        let (v1, v2) = v.split_at_mut(i + 1);
        if v1[i].is_none() {
            v1[i] = Some(vec![1,2,3]);
        }
        let data1 = v1[i].as_ref().unwrap();

        for (j, item) in (i + 1..).zip(v2.iter_mut()) {
            if do_check(i, j) {
                break
            }
            if item.is_none() {
                *item = Some(vec![1,2,3]);
            }
            let data2 = item.as_ref().unwrap();
            let res = do_cal(data1, data2);
            println!("res:{}", res);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading you, I re-edited the code

Comment: Even with 1,000,000 elements, the vector replacing the HashMap only uses 24 MB, and the use of `Option` avoids creating any more value vectors than the HashMap approach.

Comment: Note that you can get rid of the `Option`s since an empty `Vec` doesn't allocate.

Comment: And even more since all items in the `Vec` get initialized with `vec![1, 2, 3]` at some point during the function, so you might as well do it from the start and avoid the `is_none`s and `unwrap`s…